# Making a menu (color palette) from looping through colors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, colors, palette

I have the following code:

```
        foreach (Color color in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues()) 
        { 
            output.Write(color.ToString()); 
        }
```

What would be the syntax to get it to show as a color palette instead of just listing the colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
StringBuiler sb = new StringBuiler();
foreach (Color color in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())          
{             
  sb.Append(string.format("<div style=\"float:left;width:5px;height:5px;background-color:#{0}\"></div>". color.ColorCode));        
} 

ltrlColorPalette.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please note, I am working within SharePoint 2007 using CreateChildControls and HTMLWriter so it has to be a function specific to those two methods

Comment: Also your code does not work since it does not accept .color.ColorCode in asp.net 3.5

Comment: Sorry that it doesnt work, it was more meant to be some kind of semi-pseudo code.